# How to create a channel and send a message to it when user logined to server?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How add channel and send message to it by discord bot when user login?
Message should include hyper link button.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const prefix = "!";
client.on("messageCreate", function (message) {
    let guild = message.guild;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const args = commandBody.split(" ");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "ping") {
        const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
        message.reply(`Pong! This message had a latency of ${timeTaken}ms.`);
    } else if (command === "sum") {
        const numArgs = args.map((x) => parseFloat(x));
        const sum = numArgs.reduce((counter, x) => (counter += x));
        message.reply(`The sum of all the arguments you provided is ${sum}!`);
    } else if (command === "channel") {
        // Create a new text channel
        guild.channels
            .create("nft-checking", { reason: "Needed a cool new channel" })
            .then(console.log)
            .catch(console.error);
    }
});

// client.on("ready", (client) => {
//     client.channels.get("938800178314485823").send("Hello here!");
// });
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
console.log("Discord server is running.");
```

Please check this and let me know correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would send a message to the channel as you do with any other channel. To get your new channel you would access it in the `.then()` after you created it. Here's an example:

```js
guild.channels
    .create("nft-checking", { reason: "Needed a cool new channel" })
    .then(channel => {
         channel.send('I am a new channel');
    }).catch(console.error);
```

In order to run this code when a user joins, you would use the `guildMemberAdd` event.

For example:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    const guild = member.guild;
    
    guild.channels
        .create("nft-checking", { reason: "Needed a cool new channel" })
        .then(channel => {
             channel.send('I am a new channel');
        }).catch(console.error);
});
```

If you would like to make the channel restricted to the new user with permissions you can check the documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) and look at the options available.

Comment: Hello, could you show me entire working code?

Comment: You showed is part of code.
I want whole code.

Comment: This code should run when new user logined to discord server

Comment: I'm not going to write your entire code, but I edited my message to include how to do this on the user join event.